# Format option text string

Tags: asp.net, html, string, radcombobox

How can I display selected part of an asp.net string with HTML Formatting.

Eg:

```
String str= "Yerevan Airport(<B>UB21</B>,AM-ER,Yerevan,)";
```

I need to display the text enclosed in `<B>` and `</B>` in **bold** and display it as text in `RADComboBox`.

I have tried it with using StringBuilder , HttpUtility.Htmlencode, String.Format but couldn't find any proper solution.

Comment: possible replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607529/asp-net-how-to-render-html-tags-in-a-listitem-text-property

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible.

The `DropDownList` control of ASP.Net renders to a html `<select>` control which doesn't allow markup inside it's `<option>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Is it possible to get such output by using telerik RadComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  String str = "Yerevan Airport &lt;BR /&gt; UB21 &lt;BR /&gt;";
  String strHtml = Server.HtmlDecode(str);
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that `<br />` wasn't asked for, this is just manually html-encoding and then decoding which will result in exactly the same string literal the OP started with.

Comment: Hi  , I tried using the above code , but it still isnt working.Actually I want to work out this scenario on a telerik .radcombobox

Answer (score 0):

For using  RadComboBox , follow this url

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/how-to-make-a-part-of-the-radcomboboxitem-text-bold.aspx